# Importing top level file from lower level file

Tags: python

I’m unclear on this: `__init__.py` describes the current folder as a module, no?

So if my top level project folder, `my_project`, contains file `config.py` (`my_project/config.py`), then the file in `my_project/drivers/sales/customer.py` should be able to import the `config.py` module simply by:

- `import my_project.config` (Errors to: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'`)
- Or, `from .. import config` (Errors to: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`) - Btw, tried with three dots (`...`) with same error.
- Or, simply `import config` (Errors to: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`)

with the following terminal command:

```
(env) localhost:/Users/myname/Sites/my_project
$ python drivers/sales/customer.py
```

How can I accomplish this import?

Versions:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45)
```

Comment: Blowed my head recently too, im think in your case its: from .. import config as your file is 2 level deep, so 2 dots

Comment: @Kris same error. See above

Comment: Ok, last try: did you tried adding a empty __init__.py in the sales folder and then try it with from .. import config? Sorry if this feels like guessing (bc. it is !), but i still cant wrap my head arround python relative imports...

Comment: All folders in the hierarchy  need to have __init__.py file

Comment: @Kris I was wondering how but ow I know why your init is in bold :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to expose the path of your project as below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/your/project') # /Users/nabin/Desktop in my case
```

`#I have "my_project" in Desktop i.e /Users/nabin/Desktop/my_project`

Then you can do the following

```
from my_project import config
```

**So when combined, what you need is following:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/your/project')

from my_project import config
```